# Need to filter model based on make in angularjs. below code is not working model comes empty if filtered on make

Tags: angularjs, json

Need to Filter options in dropdown based on manufacturers (make). Need to filter models based on selected make option via "ng-model:make"

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="make">Make</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="make" data-ng-options="maker.make for maker in makers" required></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="make">Make</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="make" data-ng-options="maker.make for maker in makers" required></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="model">Model</label>
      <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="model" data-ng-options="availabledevice.model for availabledevice in availabledevices|filter:make" required></select>
  </div>
```

Services from factory:

```
deviceassign.factory("manufacturersoptionsservice", function($http) {
    var devicemakers = {};
    devicemakers.values = function() {
        return $http.get('api/displaymanufacturersapi.php'); 
    }
    return devicemakers;
});
deviceassign.factory("availabledeviceservice", function($http) {
    var availabledevice = {};
    availabledevice.details = function() {
        return $http.get('api/displayavailabledevicesforoptionsapi.php'); 
    }
    return availabledevice;
});
```

Controller:

```
deviceassign.controller('assigndevicecontroller', function($scope, growl, manufacturersoptionsservice, availabledeviceservice) {
    manufacturersoptionsservice.values().success(function(response1) {
        $scope.makers = response1;
    });
    availabledeviceservice.details().success(function(response3) {
        $scope.availabledevices = response3;
    });
    // ...
});
```

Comment: please format your code so people can read it

Comment: I have formatted it now. Please have a look at it.

Comment: We're not going to write the filter for you. Read the rules. Post what you have tried so far, and don't forget to RTFM. Also, you don't explain if you want your filter on your pre-rendered data or to filter the UI elements.

Comment: I am trying to do it with default filter option of angular in html.HTML has filter:make in above code. I am pretty new to angular trying to learn it

Comment: You need to post how your objects are constructed. You can't just put `filter:make`. Is that a property of `availabledevice` ?

Comment: can I post json output here?

Comment: availabledevice also has make property but make in filter should be property of makers

Comment: Thanks for formatting my code Daniel. I am actually using stackoverflow for the first time

Comment: if I use make property of availabledevice it works but it is outputting different make for each mode. Example if I have two lenovo in make corresponding to models Lenovo E530 and Lenovo E450 it is outputting Lenovo Lenovo twice in make dropdown. How to output make one time for each Lenovo E530 and 450

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.Had to select make.make as make itself is an object in JSON

```
  <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="model" data-ng-options="availabledevice.model for availabledevice in availabledevices|filter:make.make" required></select>
```